# What is the correct way to pass datetime variables into a Doctrine query?

Tags: datetime, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am looking for the right way to populate a page that contains a table of invoices that can be filtered by two datepicker fields to define a date range.

Currently, I am trying to pass the `$min` and `$max` dates as route parameters although not sure if this is the optimal way of doing it?

My current controller is:

```
/** *********************************************************************************************
 * @Route("/invoices/view/monthly-{min}-{max}"  ,name="view_monthly_invoices", defaults={"min"="2015-01-16", "max"="2016-01-17"})
 ********************************************************************************************** */
public function viewMonthlyInvoicesAction(Request $request, \DateTime $min, \DateTime $max)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $invoicesinrange = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Invoice')->invoicesWithinDates($min, $max);

    return $this->render('invoices/view.daterange.invoices.html.twig', array(
        'dues' => $invoicesinrange,
        'min'=>$min,
        'max'=>$max,
    ));
```

My Repository query is:

```
public function invoicesWithinDates($min,$max)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->select('i', 'p','g')
        ->leftJoin('i.payment_ids', 'p')
        ->leftJoin('i.member_id','m')
        ->andWhere('i.invoicedate > :min')
        ->andWhere('i.invoicedate < :max')
        ->addOrderBy('m.surnamename1', 'ASC')
        ->addOrderBy('m.surnamename2', 'ASC')
        ->setParameter('min', $min)
        ->setParameter('max', $max)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

When I go to `/invoices/view/monthly` for example, the above code is loading the page ok. `$min` and `$max` are both returning the default datetime objects correctly, however, the `$dues` is getting always getting populated with **all** invoices and not just those than within the date ranges.

Comment: Which version of Doctrine ORM do you use (you can use `composer show -i doctrine/orm` to fetch that information)? And how does your mapping configuration for the `Invoice` class look like?

Comment: Thanks @xabbuh - I got it working with Dan's answer below in the end though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try formatting the dates like this:

```
...
->setParameter('min', $min->format('Y-m-d'))
->setParameter('max', $max->format('Y-m-d'))
...
```

Comment: In case it's of help to anyone else - I got it working by tweaking the format slightly with `->format('Y-m-d h:m:s')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
->where('i.invoicedate > :min AND i.invoicedate < :max')
```